# How to compare firestore timestamps object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Get timestamp data from Firestore using CloudFunctions w/ Cloud Scheduler. Then I want to compare timestamp data.
Specifically, Cloud Functions is executed at 12:00 every day using Cloud Scheduler. I want to check if the timestamp of firestore exceeds 10 days at the time of execution. If it exceeds, execute a specific process.

If I could add 10 days to the timestamp I got from the Firestore, it would be comparable, but it didn't work. Specifically, I tried to convert timestamp to Date using toDate () and tried to add 10 days.

Comment: [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) returns object of {seconds: number, nanoseconds: number}. Depending on the precision you need, but one way to create Date is `new Date(timestamp.seconds*1000)`

Comment: Instead of describing what you tried in your code, add the actual [minimal code that reproduce the problem to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will make it much more likely that someone can spot where you went wrong. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The [Timestamp.valueOf()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#valueof) method is the simplest way to perform Timestamp comparisons using the >, <=, >= and > operators. However, if you're dealing with adding time to one of the Timestamps, it may be easiest to compare seconds like so:

```
const TEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 10;
const timestamp_a = firestore.Timestamp.now();
const timestamp_b = firestore.Timestamp.now();

console.log(timestamp_a.seconds + TEN_DAYS_IN_SECONDS > timestamp_b.seconds);
// output: true
```